# Is there a way in Flutter with Firebase to make a query to check that array does not contain document reference

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering if there is a way to make this code function another way around, so it finds all other records that do not contain this document reference?

Currently, I am building a list of records from the `Users` collection where I want to show only records that do not belong to some team.

I am using the ListView widget to display all records from the collection but I have a problem with filtering out users that have currently selected teams in their User document.
That User document contains a List of Document References to Teams Document Collection.

```
child: StreamBuilder<List<UsersRecord>>(
                  stream: queryUsersRecord(
                    queryBuilder: (usersRecord) => usersRecord.where(
                        'team_memberships',
                        arrayContains: widget.teamDocument!.reference),
              ),
```

I have tried a couple of things but I can not manage to do them so I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `whereNotIn`

Try this code:

```
child: StreamBuilder<List<UsersRecord>>(
                  stream: queryUsersRecord(
                    queryBuilder: (usersRecord) => usersRecord.whereNotIn(
                        'team_memberships',
                        [widget.teamDocument!.reference]),
              ),
```

Comment: It is nice to try but that is something that is causing an error because this is not a list so it can not be operated like that.

`The argument type 'DocumentReference<Object?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<dynamic>'.dartargument_type_not_assignable`

Comment: I am sorry, i am unable to actually test in my device , so i am suggesting some approaches, which can direct you to the answer, could you please try using `whereNotIn` clause, may be that would get you desired result , refer my updated post

Comment: I have tried to use:

   `queryUsersRecord(
        queryBuilder: (usersRecord) => usersRecord
            .where('team_memberships',
                arrayContains: widget.teamDocument!.reference)
            .where('team_memberships', isEqualTo: [])
    ),`

Or use this one:

`queryUsersRecord(
    queryBuilder: (usersRecord) => usersRecord
        .where('team_memberships', isEqualTo: widget.teamDocument!.reference)
        .where('team_memberships', isNotEqualTo: [widget.teamDocument!.reference])
)`

Comment: did you try `whereNotIn` as in my updated post

Comment: No, 'whereNotIn' also did not work in my case so I had to change the logic of how I store information about teams. I saw a nice article about how to structure this kind of code.

I don't know if it is the best but I can work with it. Here is the link to the article
https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-build-a-team-based-user-management-system-with-firebase-6a9a6e5c740d

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can query Firestore for documents that don't have a certain field or value. So you cannot query Firestore based on the absence of a particular value in an array.

Firestore queries can only return documents based on values that so exist in the document. So a value on which you need to perform the query should exist in the first place. If a document doesn't have a value for a specific field, it won't be included in an index on that field, hence the impossibility of performing that query.

Why is this not possible? This is because the number of non-existent values compared to what you already have in your database is extremely large. This means that Firestore cannot and should not create an index for all non-existing values. Querying for the non-existence of a value in an array would require a scan of all your documents, and that doesn't scale.

Perhaps you should also consider changing the array with a map:

```
$docId (document)
  |
  --- team_memberships (map)
        |
        --- referenceOne: true
        |
        --- referenceTwo: false
```

In this way, you'll always have an index for each reference.

Comment: Hey Dino. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?